# SQL Server could not run the procedure separately

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on a Winforms application in C# that was written by someone else.

I have access to the app source code and SQL Server database.

When I exec a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, that is used in App source like

```
Prc_Qry_Task_List_Unit @Month_Period =  Month_Period_cmbx.Text
```

it can not find the stored procedure to exec and returns nothing (I tried all the ways and search to execute it even search for its file one by one to find it but nothing)

But when compiling and running the main app in Visual Studio, it works fine (it can execute the stored procedure).

Application source code :

```
public static bool ExecQuery(string Query, ref DataSet ds)
{
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = Query;
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    return true;
}

// "Month_Period_cmbx.Text" And "Unit" Are user inputs
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

if (ConnMan.ExecQuery("Prc_Qry_Task_List_Unit @Month_Period = '" + Month_Period_cmbx.Text + "', @Unit = " + Unit, ref ds))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string ID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the connection string.  The server may have more than one database attached and the connection string will specify the default database.  In SQL you may need to add a "USE" statement to indicate the default database.

Comment: yea it has15 database, i used (USE) before,

Comment: Only reason you would not be able to execute stored procedure is if you didn't have the credentials.  Is SQL Server login window showing Window Credentials or SQL?  Is connection string Integrated Security (Window Credential)?

Comment: Side points: This is *really* not the way to execute stored procedures as you leave yourself open to **dangerous** SQL injection. You must pass the parameters through properly. Also I don't know what `ConnMan` does, but I hope you are disposing your connection properly immediately after use. And you don't need an adapter or a dataset here, just use `ExecuteScalar` if you only have one row, one column.